# Differentiating inverse trig function

Tags: derivatives

When differentiating $\sin^{-1}(x/2)$, I got $\frac{1}{2}(4-x^2)^{-1/2}$ but the answer I'm given does not include being multiplied by half.

Can anyone explain if the answer I'm given is right and why they did not multiply the equation by the derivative of the function in the inverse trig?

Comment: What is that four under the square root sign?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the chain rule, and then simply it algebraically. 
$$\eqalign{
  & y = si{n^{ - 1}}(x/2)  \cr 
  & y' = {1 \over {\sqrt {1 - {{(x/2)}^2}} }}*{1 \over 2} = {1 \over {2\sqrt {1 - {{{x^2}} \over 4}} }} = {1 \over {\sqrt {4 - {x^2}} }} \cr}$$

Comment: thanks for answering my question. But i am confused as to how you moved from the second last step to the last step. I would be grateful if you could clear my confusion.

Comment: Just algebra.
$${1 \over {2\sqrt {1 - {{{x^2}} \over 4}} }} = {1 \over {\sqrt 4 \sqrt {1 - {{{x^2}} \over 4}} }} = {1 \over {\sqrt {4\left( {1 - {{{x^2}} \over 4}} \right)} }} = {1 \over {\sqrt {4 - {x^2}} }}$$

Comment: genius, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\sin^{-1}(x/2)\right)' = \frac 12\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}} =
 \frac 1{2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac {x^2}{4}\right)}} $$

$$ \overset{\large*}{=}\frac 1{\sqrt{4\left(1-\left(\frac {x^2}{4}\right)\right)}}=
\frac 1{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}$$

*Note that $2 = \sqrt 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sin^{-1}(x/2)$.

$\sin(y)=x/2$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:

$\cos(y)*y'=1/2$

$y'=1/(2\cos(y))=\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{\cos(\sin^{-1}(x/2))}=\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$